# Is the stability of an ordered digraph $D$ equal to the number of pairwisely disjoint directed paths covering $D$?

Tags: graph-theory

I think there is a theorem with this statement, I'd like to know its name if it has a common one.

Also I was reading a proof for this theorem, it stated that:

> Suppose that $c<\alpha (D)$ and let $P_1, \cdots , P_c$ pairwisely disjoint directed paths covering $D$. Let $S$ be a maximum stable, then there exist $i$ such that $|P_i \cap S| \ge 2 \cdots$

But I didn't understand this step, why should there exist an $i$ with $|P_i \cap S| \ge 2$ ??

(Note that $c$ is considered as the minimum number of pairwisely disjoint paths covering $D$)

Any explanation (and completion) of this proof is appreciated, or if there is another proof its okay.

Comment: @bof I mean by ordered that if $xy \in E(D)$ and $yz \in E(D)$ then $xz \in E(D)$. And yes you are right $c$ is the minimum number ...

Comment: It is true that $c \le \alpha(D)$ for any digraph $D$, but if $D$ is an ordered digraph then we'll have that $c=\alpha (D)$

Comment: Doesn't the fact that $|P_i\cap S|\ge2$ for some $i$ just follow from the facts that $P_1,\dots,P_c$ cover $D$ and that $|S|=\alpha(D)\gt c$?

Comment: Ohh yes ! This is it, thanks a lot for your help